# How I can enable or disable Parse notifications using a checkbox? - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I have one file  calling preferencias.xml to contain a checkbox, also I have an activity called Preferencias.java, i need one thing, when the checkbox is disabled the user stops receiving notifications Push.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="op_push"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:title="Recibir Notificaciones"
    android:summary="Desactiva esta casilla si no deseas recibir más notificaciones"
    />
```

Comment: stackoverflow is an English language website. Please try a different website in your native language.

Comment: Excuseme, i try remake the question...

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml replace the line:

```
 android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
```

and I got something like this...

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.name.Receiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

where Receiver is the name of the document to the Receiver java class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver (you can create this document), in my case for onPushOpen and onReceive

```
@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
//I use this to open the correct Activity, when the notification is open
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (!sharedPrefs.contains("op_push") || sharedPrefs.getBoolean("op_push", false))
        super.onReceive(context,intent);
}
```

So when a notification arrives, the notification uses Receiver.java and through onReceiver question, preferences not contains "op_push" or "op_push" is false?, If the answer is yes, the service is not accepted.

Based on: [Let user enable/disable Push Notifications in Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28663949/5580345)